# A simple query to have a simple description of indexes

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to write **a simple query** like the one in Microsoft SQL Server :

```
SELECT S.name AS TABLE_SCHEMA, T.name AS TABLE_NAME, X.name AS INDEX_NAME, 
       C.name AS COLUMN_NAME, IC.key_ordinal AS POSITION, 
       CASE IC.is_descending_key WHEN 0 THEN 'ASC' WHEN 1 THEN 'DESC' END AS COLUM_ORDER
FROM   sys.indexes AS X
       JOIN sys.tables AS T 
          ON X.object_id = T.object_id
       JOIN sys.schemas AS S 
          ON T.schema_id = S.schema_id
       JOIN sys.index_columns AS IC 
          ON X.object_id = IC.object_id AND X.index_id = IC.index_id
       JOIN sys.columns AS C 
          ON IC.object_id = C.object_id AND IC.column_id = C.column_id
WHERE  IC.is_included_column = 0
AND    X.type BETWEEN 1 AND 2
```

To have **the complete list** of relational indexes (not other exotical indexes like spatial, GIN, BRIN....) of a PostgreSQL database ?

[image: Complete list of SQL Server relational indexes for the contextual database]

This list include one row for every column of the index.

Comment: What about `pg_indexes` - it shows the full index expression, rather than returning a row per column

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the source of the JDBC driver, because it essentially needs to return the same information.

The following will include other index types than `btree` (which are absolutely not "exotic" btw) but if you don't care about them, just add a where clause:

```
select tnsp.nspname as table_schema,
       tbl.relname as table_name, 
       ic.relname as index_name,
       case 
         when idx.indexprs is null then col.attname
         else pg_catalog.pg_get_indexdef(ic.oid, col.attnum, false)
       end as column_expression, 
       col.attnum as position,
       am.amname as index_type, 
       case am.amname
          when 'btree' then 
              case idx.indoption[col.attnum - 1] & 1 
                when 1 then 'DESC' else 'ASC' 
              end 
          else null 
        end as column_order
from pg_index idx
  join pg_attribute col on col.attrelid = idx.indexrelid
  join pg_class tbl on tbl.oid = idx.indrelid
  join pg_class ic on ic.oid = idx.indexrelid
  join pg_am am on ic.relam = am.oid
  join pg_namespace tnsp on tnsp.oid = tbl.relnamespace
where tnsp.nspname not in ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast') -- adjust here for the schema you want
order by table_schema, table_schema, index_name, col.attnum;
```

The tricky part is to deal with expressions, e.g. `on (id, upper(name) desc, abs(delta))` (something SQL Server does not have) - this is what the `pg_get_indexdef()` function resolves.

The above returns but does not identify "included" columns (e.g. `on (id) include (foo)`

If you need that a log, then you probably want to turn that into view.

Comment: SQL Server does have the equivalent of index on expression with the COMPUTED COLUMN since version 7 (1999) that can be indexed... PG chosse the Oracle way to do that but it is rarely suitable for the optimizer, except if the predicate is strictly equivelent to the index... And in SQL Server you can have COMPUED COLUMNS persistant or not, indexed or not (4 different maners).

Comment: Add a column to the table and indexing that is not the same as indexing an expression. Indexed expressions work just fine for me in Postgres and Oracle. You can create an index on a stored computed column in Postgres as well.